# Fixed header script function floatHead is adding an extra thead

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make fixed headers for a table in my view.  I searched and didn't find much so I ended up trying a plugin found here http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/. After implementing its adding an extra blank thead to my `tblPersons` table that looks like this:

[image]

So then I try and hide the `thead` using this jquery code (i have two total theads on the view, this selects the one I need via the id, or lack thereof):

```
$('thead[id!="personsHeader"]').hide();
```

Which does remove the `thead`, but then it removes the first line of my results which is:

```
Kirk | Alexander | 06/02/2015
```

Visual:
[image]

It doesn't make sense to me because the `thead` is separate from the `tbody` where the `Kirk row` is located...

[image]

Finally for reference, here is my `View` form code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Persons"))
{
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <table id="tablePanelHeader" class="table table-bordered menu-options">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Persons Pages:
                    @Html.DropDownList("PersonsDDL", new SelectList(listItems, "Value", "Text"))
                </td>
                <td>
                    Search filter: <input type="text" id="search" ="Type to search">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="rowCount">

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <table id="tblPersons" class="table table-bordered">
            <thead id="personsHeader">
                <tr class="page-header">
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Birthdate</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @item.firstname
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.lastname
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.birthdate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
                        </td>


         </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

}

I've given it my best shot and now I'm turning to the professionals... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using jQuery data tables instead.

Comment: Also if you want to keep using this tool, you might want to inspect that row under the header that also gets displayed.

Comment: If you can come up with a better solution for fixed headers, im all ears. Ill dump this tool asap @Gjohn

Comment: https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html this is essentially what you are looking for right?

Comment: I'd prefer to not rewrite my entire html contents.  For future projects ill certainly consider this.  However for now, I'd like to make this work. @Gjohn

Comment: next time make an issue on github, but i am glad you solved it with css

Comment: @mkoryak why make an issue on github?  Sorry to ask, just never have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Personally I have always been a fan of going full css instead of adding the bloat of js to this mix.

See this for an example of a fixed table header with just css - http://codepen.io/tjvantoll/pen/JEKIu

```
.fixed_headers {
   width: @table_width;
   table-layout: fixed;
   border-collapse: collapse;

   th { text-decoration: underline; }
   th, td {
       padding: 5px;
       text-align: left;
   }

   td:nth-child(1), th:nth-child(1) { min-width: @column_one_width; }
   td:nth-child(2), th:nth-child(2) { min-width: @column_two_width; }
   td:nth-child(3), th:nth-child(3) { width: @column_three_width; }

   thead {
     background-color: @header_background_color;
     color: @header_text_color;
     tr {
     display: block;
     position: relative;
   }
 }
 tbody {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: @table_body_height;
    tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: @alternate_row_background_color;
  }
 }
}
```

If you are set on using a javascript library try jQuery Datatables - datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html

Comment: Nice.  I'm a css noob.  This table is used with bootstrap, is there anyway i canchange these fixed widths in your css?

Comment: Modified the code and got it working , something like this minus my bootstrap css http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGYXBz